# Android Native : Want to record an audio call made from default keypad of phone?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, avaudiorecorder, call-recording

I am developing an app where user can make a call using a keypad which opens inside app but call will be made from primary sim of mobile. Here I want to record this call having voice of both caller and receiver. I have tried multiple libraries but nothing seems to work properly. Following libraries I have tried but didn't got needed results :

https://github.com/BeatriceFendt/android-call-recorder

https://github.com/AnthonyNahas/android-auto-call-recorder

https://github.com/aykuttasil/CallRecorder

https://github.com/ivanzotov/CallRecorder

I have also tried this library as well but it recorded my own voice but not of receiver.

https://github.com/synapticweb/CallRecorder

Any help or clarification will be appreciated. Just want to know if it is possible and if it is then how we can do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "are there any legal issues came along with Android 10" -- please talk to a qualified attorney about the legal issues in your area involved with recording voice communications.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am not able to record voice of both users (Caller and Receiver). Can you recommend me any library or piece of code using which I can achieve recording ?

Comment: Sorry, I have never attempted to record voice calls, as that has serious legal implications.

Comment: @AnupamBaldi did you get success with the call recording app?

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede This is now restricted by Google so you cannot record SIM card calls anymore. Instead, you can use call recording of those mobile phones where the call recording feature is available inbuilt.

Comment: @AnupamBaldi is there any other way available to record the call which devices has not inbuild feature ??

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede Unfortunately no, there is no such way to record call made via SIM.